# Ghusl Janabat or Ghusl to remove impurities

Tags: ghusl

A lot of different sites have different methods of how to perform ghusl janabat or ghusl that is performed after the ejaculation of semen which is why I am so curious whether the one I am doing is even right or wrong.

Can you help me with the right process step by step and with any reference or anything..

Comment: This could be "too broad". Why not post the interesting parts from those sources and then highlight the portion your struggling with or ask to compare. It should be better that way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to perform Ghusl? And is my ghusl valid?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/47944/how-to-perform-ghusl-and-is-my-ghusl-valid)

Answer (score 1):

Assalaamu alaikum warehmatullahi wabarkatehu, 
The best and most accurate way of doing gusul is the way our Prophet did! You have Hadith to refer from for every issue and not sites because not all sites tell the right ways or paths. The following:

## Volume 1, Book 5, Number 265 :

Narrated by Maimuna

I placed water for the bath of Allah's Apostle and he poured water over his hands and washed them twice or thrice; then he poured water with his right hand over his left and washed his private parts (with his left hand). He rubbed his hand over the earth and rinsed his mouth and washed his nose by putting water in it and blowing it out. After that he washed his face, both fore arms and head thrice and then poured water over his body. He withdrew from that place and washed his feet.

## Volume 1, Book 5, Number 252 :

Narrated by Abu Ja'far

While I and my father were with Jabir bin 'Abdullah, some People asked him about taking a bath He replied, "A Sa' of water is sufficient for you." A man said, "A Sa' is not sufficient for me." Jabir said, "A Sa was sufficient for one who had more hair than you and was better than you (meaning the Prophet)." And then Jabir (put on) his garment and led the prayer.

So, in short you do niyah (intention of cleaning yourself for prayer or ibadah) then wash your hands 3 times and private part 3 times then do wudu/Abolution while saying Bismillah (in toilet you can recite it in your head) but washing your feet a little away from your place of bath. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all , all praises and thanks are due to Allah . After that , to take ritual birth is compulsory for the muslim person because his or her salah will not be valid until he or she purifies from the janaabah . And in order for you to purify yourself from the the janaabah , follow the following steps .

Step 1 come with the intention that you want to purify yourself.

Step 2 wash the affected areas （i.e, your private parts ）.

Step 3 take complete wudhuu or incomplete wudhuu .

Step 4 take a full hand of water and pour it on the right side of your head . And another full hand of water On the left side of your head . And another full hand of water for the middle of your head making sure that all your hairs are wet before starting the shower .And if you start the shower ,keep your hands away from your private parts so that not to touch them and invalidate your ablution. Finally,  if you are done with the shower you can renew your ablution or not to renew and you can pray with it .

＊ incomplete wudhuu is

Taking the wudhuu in the normal way but not Washing the feet . You will wash your feet after you are done with the ritual bath. And Allah knows best .

والسلام عليكم ورحمة اللّٰه وبركاته

Answer (score 0):

All Praise to Allah Swt and blessings on Prophet Muhammad peace be upon him His Family and Companions.

**There are 3 Fardh in ghusl**,

> 1.Rinsing the mouth.
>
> 2.Sniffing water upto nose.
>
> 3.Washing every visible part of the entire body

Now The Sunnah way of Ghusl:

**1**.Without Pronouncing anything verbally make an intention in your heart
   to perform Ghusl (I am performing Ghusl in order to purify myself)

**2**. First wash both hands upto your wrist 3 times and then wash the
   private parts(regardless of whether you could see any impurity).

**3**.Then
   wash any impurity from your body( if any).

**4**.Perform whole wudhu the
   way you would for Salah including rinsing of mouth and sniffing upto
   nose ,but do not wash your feet(unless you are standing on something
   elevated like a stool).

**5**.Rub water on your whole body like Oil.Pour
   water three time over your right shoulder,then three times over the
   left and then same no of times over your head and the rest of the
   entire body.

**6**.Now wash your feet. Do not face the Holy Kaaba while
   performing Ghusl and rub your hands all over body whilst washing
   (washing means at least 2 drops of water has passed over an area) and
   do not talk while doing ghusl,there is no harm in drying oneself with
   a towel after finishing.

---

*From Book of Hanafi jurisprudence*

**Narrated Hisham bin `Urwa:
(on the authority of his father)`Aisha said,
 "Whenever Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) took the bath of Janaba, he cleaned his hands and performed ablution like that for prayer and then took a bath and rubbed his hair, till he felt that the whole skin of the head had become wet, then he would pour water thrice and wash the rest of the body." `Aisha further said, "I and Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) used to take a bath from a single water container, from which we took water simultaneously."([Bukhari](http://www.sunnah.com/bukhari/5/25))**

Allah Swt and His Messenger knows best.