# Should I wait forty days after unintentional drinking before getting married?

Tags: nikah, alcohol

Alhumdulliah, I'm going to marry within a few days. Unfortunately, I had an event 10 days ago and I drunk wine unintentionally. As far as I know if anyone get drunk, for the next 40 days his/her prayer will not approved to Allah. Can anyone please tell me, will my marriage be approved by Allah or do I need to change my marriage date to after the 40 days?

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. Please consider taking some time to learn more about our site and model by taking our 2min. [tour] and checking our [help]. I strongly recommed you to read [answer].

Comment: Honestly speaking even if we assume you did drink intenionally what would be the benefit of not praying 40 days? Isn't it even a bigger sin? Anything which is done by mistake doesn't count! So if you once realized you are drinking alcohol stopped from that you are only asked to repent.

Answer (score -2):

look we are civilized people.
this problem is off the table now. no need to wait for 40 days. you saad you didnt know you're drinking the wine.so its not on purpose. but if its really bother you, you can take a ghusl.

note: if you did it on purpose so you have to take a ghusl.dont do any holy actions like pray or else until you take a ghusl.

For instructions regarding how to perform ghusl,
[check this question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/27924/ghusl-janabat-or-ghusl-to-remove-impurities).

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam we are **not a typical internet froum**. Please consider taking some time to learn more about our site and model by taking our [tour] and checking our [help]. I strongly recommed you to read [answer].