# Is my Ghusl Right?

Tags: halal-haram, salat, wudu, ghusl

Salaam. As it is very hot in my city. I continuously have been ejaculating sperm(maniy) every night I sleep. I don't know why does this happens but every morning I woke up it's wet down there. I woke up at 12pm and at 1pm I have to go to My Coaching centre. Today I woke up with wetness down there. I didn't had time so i didn't took a soap bath. I performed every part of the Ghusl but only applied soap on my Private parts because sperm only remained in my private parts. I didn't applied soap on My full body but only put water on my upper body. Is my Ghusl valid? Is it allowed to not apply soap in a Ghusl?

Answer (score 1):

I know of no evidence that the prophet ever required — or even *used* — soap to perform the minor or major ablutions. As long as your intent was appropriate and all applicable body parts are touched by pure clean water, your ghusl will be valid.

See also: [Ghusl Janabat or Ghusl to remove impurities](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/27924/22)